# Capture adjacent Cell with condition Ask Question

Tags: excel-formula

Capture adjacent Cell with condition

I have values in A column and corresponding values in B column. I need to capture based on A column value I need to capture adjacent cell value which has no zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want to retrieve a value from column **B** that corresponds to *alpha* in column **A**, but which is not 0.  We can use an array formula with `MATCH()`to achieve this:

First place:

alpha

in cell **D1** and in **E1** enter the array formula:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,(A:A=$D$1)*(B:B<>0),0),1)
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

[image]